# Deploying multiple features from multiple projects as single wsp package - visual studio 2010 support

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, wsp

I have got SharePoint Workflow project X and SharePoint event receiver project Y.
I have featureX in workflow project and featureY in evet receiver project Y.
I want to deploy both projects in single wsp package. 
Can I add featureY to the workflow project X ?
OR should I create 3rd project with features and somehow import both features - event handler and workflow ? If yes - how to do this using VS 2010 ? 
Thanks in advance for the answer.

I have found the answer in the following link.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/multiple-sharepoint-projects-in-one-solution-how-to-package-correctly

**The solution is to create new (empty) SharePoint project and open file Package.package in Package Viewer. Then you can move all features within solution from / to the package.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer on below link.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/multiple-sharepoint-projects-in-one-solution-how-to-package-correctly

The solution is to create new (empty) SharePoint project and open file Package.package in Package Viewer. Then you can move all features within solution from / to the package.